# How to print text using cout after pressing enter?

Tags: c++, cout

Which command lets me to cout my new random numbers by presing enter? I tried to write system("pause") but then comes line "press any key to continue" which I dont like. Is there any possibility to just press enter button and see numbers one after one?

Here's the program code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    int i, k;

    srand(time(0));
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << (rand() % 8) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try cin.readline() or if you can get away with not having to listen for enter specifically then cin.readchar().

Comment: nope :) Really, I can't figure it out how to do it..

Comment: @M.Babcock: aren't you getting confused with the `Console` object of the .NET Framework?

Comment: Why would you even want that? What a silly sort of program would gobble up arbitrary amounts of input as part of its normal operation? That'd be totally useless in any composition chain... just focus on writing something that's actually useful.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: You're right. I've updated it.

Comment: it won't work cuz when I type "cin.readline()" it gives error - "class cin has no member "readline" ..

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <limits>

// ...

cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

The advantage over reading a single character is that this will make sure that no stray characters are left over into the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more modern C++ take on it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rng(std::time(0));
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> gen(0,7);

    for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        std::cout << gen(rng);

        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
    };
}
```

Comment: @KerrekSB g++ still eating it like a baby, which is why I keep forgetting without noting.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `getchar()` which will read one keypress and then continue. If you want to specifically break on the enter key, use something like `while (getchar() != "\n");`

Comment: Do not use getch. It is non-standard. Use getchar.

Comment: getch is Borland C (and perhaps MSVC as well) extension to standard C via conio library. it's not part of the standard, and surely not available (by default) in most compilers (incl. gcc)

Comment: That's what I get for using Google :-) Updated - I always use `cin` myself, but that produces output.

Comment: Should be single quotes around \n. '\n'. "\n" is a cstring, not a char.

Answer (score 0):

add `cin >> SomeVariableThatCouldAcceptAnythingInCaseYouPressSomethingElseBeforeTheEnterKey` either before or after the `cout`, whichever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Just read a string, right?

```
#include <string>
....


for (i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    std::string str;
    cin >> str; // this should pause until the user presses enter
    cout << (rand()%8) << endl;

};
```

Comment: I think this waits until you really put at least one non-whitespace character in, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple `cin.get()`? No need for any temporary variable nor any C functions.